# Build Artifacts for Teamcity with MSbuild not working, want to pass it to powershell variable for deployment function

Tags: .net, visual-studio, teamcity

I have a .net core api project that is building correctly using teamcity. It does not create build artifacts.

In Administration and general settings for the project i have tried setting up relative and absolute path both in artifacts path. I have tired setting multiple paths none is working for me.

+: ProjectName/*.* => artifacts.zip

tried this as well

+: *.* => artifacts.zip

Tried this

+: artifacts

Tried this

+: d:\artifacts

I have tried multiple combinations but none is working

what i want to do is that i have the solution project in root folder with multiple folder for the project. I want all those artifacts to be in a zip file or a folder which has all the artifacts for deployment

I have to use it for asp.net web applications too.

Also want to know how i can pass it to powershell command runner as a parameter/variable to use for deployment purpose.

I am new to Teamcity. I have tried lot of combinations for this but not working for having artifacts.

Please let me know about details about setting up deployment artifacts path.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was that i was not checking out repository from Version Control System.

Once i did that, it worked like a charm. For powershell i am looking at Artifact dependency